# How to divide a number into specific values contained in an array with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

2I have the following array of numbers and the following number:

```
var array= [0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 150, 250, 500];
var number = 1845;
```

"desired result" --> [500, 500, 500, 250, 50, 40, 5]

I need to find a way to come up with the optimal combination of numbers included in the above array so that their addition creates the given number. The code must work this way because the acceptable numbers are only the ones in the array. So instead of 1845 I need to return 500,500,500,250,50,40,5.

This is my code but it doesn't work as I expect.

```
array = array.reverse();
var values = new Array();
var sts = $.inArray(number, array);
if (sts != -1){
    return number;
} else {
    for (k=0; k<array.length; k++){
        if ((number - array[k]) > 0){
            values.push(array[k]);
            number = number - array[k];
        }
    }
    return values.toString();
}
```

Comment: Do your homework, then you can watch TV

Comment: Good for you. So what did you try so far?

Comment: Obviously this is something you should do. However if you have any specific problem in your code maybe we can help.

Comment: I apologize for not including my code but it is not functional. I editted the post.

Comment: I have voted for reopen the question, wait to see if other will do the same

Comment: @AlonEitan thank you..

Comment: you changed the requirement. or so. the former leads to use only one item, now, you can use more than one.

Answer (score 1):

This proposal iterates all possible combinations of the given items and uses some short circuit for reducing the iterations/recursions.

It stops if the sum of the right side (a potential result set) is greater than the wanted sum and if sum of all items (left and right) is smaller than the wanted sum.

```js
function getParts(array, sum) {
    function add(a, b) { return a + b; }

    function iter(left, right) {
        var sumRight = right.reduce(add, 0);
        left = left.slice();
        if (sumRight >= sum) {
            sumRight === sum && result.push(right);
            return;
        }
        if (!left.length || left.reduce(add, 0) + sumRight < sum) {
            return;
        }
        iter(left, right.concat(left.pop()));
        iter(left, right.concat([]));
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(array, []);
    result.sort(function (a, b) { return a.length - b.length; });
    return result;
}

function print(o) {
    document.write('<pre>length: ' + o.length + ' ' + JSON.stringify(o, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
}

print(getParts([0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 150, 250], 5000));
print(getParts([0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 150, 250], 495));
```

Comment: But the number might be grater than 495. If you try the code with 5000 then it "breaks".

Comment: it returns an empty array with `number = 5000`.

Comment: maybe the edit helps you. it is now compact in one function.

Comment: I need it to work for every possible number given and not only for numbers smaller than the the sum of the numbers in the array.

Comment: please give an example with the array and the wanted sum.

Answer (score 0):

The idea behind these problems is that you will want to check every possible solution in the smartest way possible. [A* pathfinding](https://qiao.github.io/PathFinding.js/visual/) is something you would need to learn in order to do this problem justice. Basically you tell the computer what data is the best to choose from in a list, then check if that is the answer. If it isn't the answer, then evaluate the cost to the next answer and repeat.

These type of questions have been around since before I was born. [Getting to all 50 state capitols](http://www.randalolson.com/2015/03/08/computing-the-optimal-road-trip-across-the-u-s/) is one of those types of questions.

The long and short of it, is that you will need to recursively go through every solution until you have found the one that matches. the worst case scenario is **O(2^n-1)**. The best case scenario is **O(1)**.

Implementing the A* path finding algorithm or other similar types of cost/benefit algorithms will get you where you need to go faster. But you will need to learn how to implement them via JavaScript.

Comment: actually, its is 2^n-1 for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Here is the answer.

```
array = array.reverse();
var values = new Array();
var sts = $.inArray(number, array);
if (sts != -1){
    return number;
} else {
    function iter(){
        if ((number - array[k]) > 0){
            values.push(array[k]);
            number = number - array[k];
            iter();
        }
    }
    for (k=0; k<array.length; k++){
        iter();
    }
    return values.toString();
}
```